# why erase function is giving error in string function?

Tags: c++

The erase function is giving an error of invalid arguments but I have passed

**1st argument** = index no.
 **2nd argument** = no. of characters

then also it is giving error.
**Eg**

```
word3 = word2.erase(word.begin(), word.length()/2-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase (1) you see that you need to pass the *index* of the first character to erase and the number of how many characters to erase. You pass an iterator instead as the first argument. Just do

```
word3 = word2.erase(0, word.length()/2 -1);
//                     ^^^^
//                     this should probably be word2
```

or use the (3) overload that accepts a range:

```
word3 = word2.erase(word2.begin(), std::next(word2.begin(), word2.length()/2 -1));
```

I also believe you should have `word2` inside your `erase`, not `word`.

Answer (score 0):

Member function `begin()` of class `std::string` returns iterator. That is its return type either `std::string::iterator` or `std::string::const_iterator`.

You are trying to use member function `erase` that has parameters of type `std::string::size_type`:

```
basic_string& erase(size_type pos = 0, size_type n = npos);
```

If you want to use this member function you should write the call like

```
word2.erase( 0, word.length()/2 - 1 )
```

If you want to use the function that uses iterators that is the following member function

```
iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

then the call can look like

```
word2.erase( word.begin(), std::next( word.begin(), word.length()/2 - 1 ) )
```

or simply

```
word2.erase( word.begin(), word.begin() + word.length()/2 - 1 )
```

I hope that is not a typo that you call the function for object with name `word2` and in the expression used as the argument you use object with name `word`